# MediaWiki Template:Notice import not quite right

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I exported Template:Notice from MediaWiki and tried to import it into my MediaWiki instance, but it looks like I did something wrong.

MediaWiki:

[image]

My instance:

[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I might be missing for the images and /!\ box styling.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons come from Wikimedia Commons, Wikimedia's media repository. Set [`$wgUseInstantCommons`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseInstantCommons) to true to enable InstantCommons which "allows to automatically use in the local wiki images hosted in Wikimedia Commons".

As for the message box styles, refer to [Module:Message box/ambox.css](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Module:Message_box/ambox.css). You can put the styles in your site's MediaWiki:Common.css or install and configure [Extension:TemplateStyles](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateStyles) and import the relevant stylesheets.

Comment: Thank you.  Setting $wgUseInstantCommons worked.  I have TemplateStyles installed.  How do I configure it to import the ambox.css stylesheet?