# MediaWiki: why imported template look so terrible?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

At the beginning of this page you can see this template which doesn't show properly:
https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Iva_assorbenti_al_4%25,_%C3%A8_una_strumentalizzazione%3F

I've copied the template from [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Bozza), but the image (and probably the css) wasn't copied correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68569533/15517071) for setting up InstantCommons to use media from Wikimedia Commons.

For the inputboxes, you have to install the [InputBox extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:InputBox).